# I can't create a new Dataframe with the columns I want

Tags: python

I am trying to extract 3 columns so that I can create a graph later.

```
newDF = df.loc[filt,['Dublin','Cork','Galway']]
print(newDF)
```

but unfortunately I get an error :

> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['Dublin'],
> dtype='object')

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_df = df[['Dublin', 'Cork', 'Galway']]
```

Comment: Well, then 'Dublin' is not in your index. Then it would be helpful to see what your data looks like.

Comment: thank you, exactly this was the problem in my csv file "Dublin" was with white space